# 404 Resource not found on all views

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.6.1

I have an old project that I have never worked with and need to get running which is using .NET Framework 4.6.

1. Had warnings about misssing references (Antrl3.Runtime, EntityFramework. ExcelDataReader and many more)
2. I used the Update-Package -reinstall command in Nuget package manager console which seems to have resolved these warnings
3. I launch the app but get a Not Found - HTTP ERROR 404. The requested resource is not found.

If I set a breakpoint in the Home controller and try to access one of the controllers methods through the url path then it does not hit the breakpoint and still gives me the requested resource is not found error.

If I right click on a View -> View in Browser it also gives me the same 404 error page.
If I open my Home -> Index.cshtml view then an error shows up:
`>  "Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error   CS1980  Cannot define a class or member that utilizes 'dynamic' because the compiler required type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DynamicAttribute' cannot be found. Are you missing a reference? 1_Views_Home_Index.cshtml   1   Active"`
If I open a different view I get another error:
`Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error   CS0012  The type 'Expression<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.    2_Views_EditData.cshtml     25  Active`

I've tried cleaning, rebuilding the project, setting the target framework version to a previous one and then setting it back to 4.6, changing the Microsoft.AspNet.MVC package version but that did not help.
Not sure where to look for the problem, in the Solution Explorer the References do not have any warnings or errors.
Any advice on how to diagnose this issue?

Answer (score 0):

What VS version are you using? There is not enough information you might need to downgrade the MVC package version but first try the following with a clean version of the old project.

With regards to the first error:

> CS1980  Cannot define a class or member that utilizes 'dynamic'
> because the compiler required type
> 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DynamicAttribute' cannot be found.
> Are you missing a reference? 1_Views_Home_Index.cshtml

Change framework 4.6 back to 4.5.* (try: 4.5.2), then set it back to 4.6
Do a clean build (also try restoring Nuget packages)

With regards to the second error:

> CS0012  The type 'Expression<>' is defined in an assembly that is not
> referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Core,
> Version=4.0.0.0

Add a reference to System.Core 4.0.0.0 and close/reopen the cshtml.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2022
Changed framework 4.6 back to 4.5.2, then set it back to 4.6
Did a clean build and tried restoring Nuget packages (Got the messsage: All packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore)
I have 69 warnings that are like this: The referenced component 'System.Web' could not be found 
When I try to Add System.Core 4.0.0.0 reference I get an error: A reference to 'System.Core' could not be added. This component is already automatically referenced by the build system. I added the <Reference Include="System.Core", Version=4.0.0.0"> manually

Comment: Also in the view I am getting multiple errors like this now: The type or namespace naame 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Go to Nuget Package Manager  and install Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc and try avoid manual changes :)

Comment: Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc is already installed, I tried uninstalling it and installing it again with the same version it currently had (5.2.4) but I get the same error

Comment: try this on the PM console: update-package -reinstall Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc

Comment: Tried it and I have the following errors:
CS0115 '_Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml.Execute()': no suitable method found to override
CS1980 Cannot define a class or member that utilizes 'dynamic' because the compiler required type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DynamicAttribute' cannot be found. 
CS0103 The name 'Context' does not exist in the current context
CS0103 The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context
CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) 1_Views_Home_Index.cshtml

Comment: What version of MvcWebRazorHostFactory is on the web.config in views folder?

Comment: Version=5.2.4.0